# CSS changes made on child theme not showing up in website

Tags: css, wordpress

I've made changes to style.css in the child theme of wordpress but the changes don't show up. I made a major change by changing the background color with the following code:

```
.main{
    background: #ffffff
{
```

I've cleared the cache and even used another laptop to look at my site to no avail. What is the matter?

Comment: Is your CSS file getting loaded?

Comment: Have you tried using the Developer Tools, within Google Chrome, to confirm whether the Child Theme's CSS Stylesheet renders.  You can also check the Source Code but if you use the Developer Tools, you can modify the CSS, in real time.  This could be useful, for you, in determining whether you are using the right CSS Selector(s).  Furthermore, it could be that your CSS is being overridden by the Parent Theme/Plugin.  As such, you may want to make use of the `!important` entry, as to prevent such overriding.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell from what you've provided. The 3 most likely causes are:

1. You are not linking to your stylesheet properly

   *(are you sure your style.css or however is called is properly linked via link rel in your html document?)*
2. You did not save changes to your html and css files before refreshing the page.
3. You are not using proper selectors (eg. your have a `div id="main"`) and you  are referencing it as `.main` instead of `#main`

Answer (score 0):

Because you have an opening bracket where you should have a closing bracket.

Your code should be as follows:

.main { 
background: #ffffff 
}

Answer (score 0):

you need to enqueue your child theme's stylesheet as well. Modify your functions.php using the code snippet below. Note that the template directory refers to the parent theme's directory and the stylesheet directory refers to the active child theme.

```
<?php
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

Here's a [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to the official documentation